# Translating a Pygments regexp to JFlex

Tags: python, regex, pygments, jflex

I'm trying to build a lexer for Markdown in JFlex; I'm looking at the source for Pygments:

For example, [this](https://github.com/jhermann/pygments-markdown-lexer/blob/704b72bc6881e8c062593c01faacf8455b2fa159/src/pygments_markdown_lexer/lexer.py#L66) is the rule for horizontal rule:

```
(r'^\s*\n(?:\s*[-*_]){3,}\s*\n', Markdown.Markup)
```

I'm naïvely writing this in my `.flex` file:

```
^\s*\n(?:\s*[-*_]){3,}\s*\n { return token(TokenType.KEYWORD2); }
```

This just gives me errors:

```
Error in file "/home/hhrutz/Documents/devel/SyntaxPane/src/main/jflex/de/sciss/syntaxpane/lexers/markdown.flex" (line 294): 
Syntax error.
  ^\s*\n(?:\s*[-*_]){3,}\s*\n { return token(TokenType.KEYWORD2); }
         ^

Error in file "/home/hhrutz/Documents/devel/SyntaxPane/src/main/jflex/de/sciss/syntaxpane/lexers/markdown.flex" (line 294): 
Syntax error.
  ^\s*\n(?:\s*[-*_]){3,}\s*\n { return token(TokenType.KEYWORD2); }
                   ^

Error in file "/home/hhrutz/Documents/devel/SyntaxPane/src/main/jflex/de/sciss/syntaxpane/lexers/markdown.flex" (line 294): 
Unexpected character 
  ^\s*\n(?:\s*[-*_]){3,}\s*\n { return token(TokenType.KEYWORD2); }
                      ^
JFlex.GeneratorException: Generation aborted
```

Comment: @Jan yes, but I have no idea how to fix it. Can you help? For example if I just remove `?:`, the next error about `{3,}` remains.

Comment: For example, I can write `^\s*\n(\s*[-*_]){3,99}\s*\n` but according to [Java patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) I should be able to write `{3,}`. How do I specify "at least three occurrences"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible to specify a minimum number of occurrences. Here's my attempt to implement what ["commonmark"](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/#thematic-break) specifies for horizontal rules:

> A line consisting of 0-3 spaces of indentation, followed by a sequence of three or more matching `-`, `_`, or `*` characters, each followed optionally by any number of spaces, forms a thematic break.

```
space               = " "
spacesOpt           = [ ]*

^{space}{0,3}(\-{spacesOpt}\-{spacesOpt}(\-{spacesOpt})+ | \*{spacesOpt}\*{spacesOpt}(\*{spacesOpt})+ | \_{spacesOpt}\_{spacesOpt}(\_{spacesOpt})+)\n { return ... }
```

Is there a better way to express this?